# pandas: Get the maximum value in a row, and record the column where it was found?

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe df:

```
a     b     c
1.2   2    0.1
2.1   1.1  3.2
0.2   1.9  8.8
3.3   7.8  0.12
```

I'm trying to get the max value from each row of the dataframe, *and* record the column from which it came.

I can do `df['max_value'] = df.max(axis=1)` to get the maximum value in a new column, but how can I record the column from which it came?

Comment: Use `df['max_col'] = df.idxmax(axis=1)`

Comment: I get `ValueError: could not convert string to float: a`.

Comment: Maybe there is problem some bad values in numeric, first check first row if not mixed columns names with values.

Comment: If still problem and data mixed in some row, need `df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')`